# Why does my bash script think an argument is not present?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a simple bash script that would execute as follows

```
$ ./export.sh -n <my-file-name> -a <my-api-key>
```

I am using this as a way to pass some arguments at build time in a Go project.

A very simple version of the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts n:a option
do
case "${option}"
in
n) FILENAME=${OPTARG};;
a) APIKEY=${OPTARG};;
esac
done

if [ -z "$FILENAME" ]
then
   FILENAME=downloader
fi

if [ -z "$APIKEY" ]
then
   echo "[ERROR] Missing API key"
   exit 1
fi

cd src && go build -o ../build/${FILENAME}.exe downloader -ldflags "-X api.APIServiceKey="${APIKEY}
```

If the `FILENAME` does not exist I provide a default value, however if `APIKEY` is missing I would like to exist and show a message.

Running the script with all arguments however throws the error as if `APIKEY` was missing.

Comment: "... however if APIKEY is missing I would like to exist and ..." : I can confirm you actually exiSt ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a colon in the `getopts` call. Since you expect an argument to `-a`, there must be a colon after it in the optstring: `while getopts n:a: option`

Quoting the getopts man page:

> When  the option requires an option-argument, the getopts utility shall
>   place it in the shell variable OPTARG. [...] If a character is followed
>   by a <colon>, the option shall be expected to have an argument which
>   should be supplied as a separate argument.